# When ever I teleport it gives me the sword but I cant do anything with it other than hold it, anyone know why?

Tags: lua, roblox

the script for the teleporter

```
local ClickDetector = script.Parent.ClickDetector
local TP = script.Parent.Parent.TP2

ClickDetector.MouseClick:Connect(function(plr)
    plr.Character:MoveTo(TP.Position)
end)
```

the script for giving the player the sword when the player teleports

```
local player = script.Parent
local humanoid = player:WaitForChild("Humanoid")
local backpack = game.Players.LocalPlayer.Backpack
local ClickDetector = game.Workspace.TP1.ClickDetector
local sword = game.ReplicatedStorage.ClassicSword

ClickDetector.MouseClick:Connect(function()
    sword:Clone().Parent = backpack
end)
```

Comment: Does the sword work before you teleport?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sword has to be given on a server-sided script (normal script).
Here's what you should do in your teleporter script:

```lua
local ClickDetector = script.Parent.ClickDetector
local TP = script.Parent.Parent.TP2
local sword = game.ReplicatedStorage.ClassicSword

ClickDetector.MouseClick:Connect(function(plr)
    -- Teleport player
    plr.Character:MoveTo(TP.Position)
    
    -- Give a sword to the player
    sword:Clone().Parent = plr.Backpack
end)
```

With this, you don't need the second script you showed.

Mark this as an answer if this was indeed what solved your problem.

You should ask questions in the [Roblox Devforum](https://devforum.roblox.com/) instead because over there is way more active.